# Having trouble with overlay on iOS

Tags: html, ios, css

I'm having the following overlay in my web app

```
<div class="hform overlay">
  <h3>Form caption</h3>             
  <form>
    <!-- here be some inputs -->                          
    <button type="submit">Show</button>         
  </form>                                       
</div>
```

in CSS I have

```
.container .overlay {
  display:none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.90);
  width: 100%;
}

.container .hform.open {
  display: block;
}
```

When an ovelay is shown class `.open` is added.

The problem is that on iOS it's impossible to hit "Show" button. Can someone tell me why?